# Is it possible to create an activity under another activity in android?

Tags: android, video, android-activity

I want to play a video file on full screen and for that I have created an activity and put a button for closing it after that the video is finished.

But, now I think if I create a separate activity for each video then it will create a storage problem in the future.
Is it possible to create an activity inside the main activity?

My second question is: Is it possible to create an activity on runtime on demand?
Also, after finishing the work can we destroy the space allocated by the object for that activity?

If we can do this in android then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0% accepted rate?

Form your questions a bit better please, i have no idea if i got it right

[VideoViewDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html) shows you that you can simply change video path, and another video will be shown.

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
```

This is done while app is running, so you will only need one activity for all videos.

This is how you get your video path between activities:

Main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("VIDEO_URL", "your_video_url");
b.putString("VIDEO_NAME", "Teh Video");
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

And catch that in VideoActivity in onCreate:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String path = b.getString("VIDEO_URL");
String video_name = b.getString("VIDEO_NAME");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to call other Activity from the Activity.And what you mean to destroy the activity ,you simply can call finish() from an activiry.So previous activity will come in the foreground.However you can't create an activity at runtime.You must have to define it previously in your manifest file